# Is there way to push NewRelic error manually?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic

In our Rails app we rescue most of the exceptions on ApplicationController to give correct API response, but still want to track errors happening using ErrorCollector. Is there a way to manually send error to NewRelic?

Answer (score 41):

Based on what I see in the New Relic agent code you can do

`NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(exception, options)`

I have tested this and have this running in my stack

Here's an example in a controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid, with: :rescue_invalid_record

  private

  def rescue_invalid_record(exception)
    NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(exception)
  end
end
```

Comment: Here's the documentation for this: http://rdoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent:notice_error

It's basically an alias to the method Igor included in his solution, except it returns nil instead of the exception. So while it behaves a little differently, it's essentially the same thing and much less verbose.

Comment: To add more context I precede that with: NewRelic::Agent.add_custom_attributes({ custom_params: params.to_unsafe_h.merge(current_user: current_user.id), uri: request.original_url })

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it's recommended way to use, but this works perfectly:

```
NewRelic::Agent.agent.error_collector.notice_error( exception )
```

Comment: I work at New Relic. While this method may work today, it is *not* part of our public API, and thus shouldn't be used - it may change at any point in the future. The correct method to use is `NewRelic::Agent.notice_error`, as noted in nort's response. Anything that's not documented in our public [API docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm) falls into the same category.

Answer (score 1):

Full documentation of the API call to notice errors and increment the error metric is the New Relic Ruby Agent API documentation here http://rdoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent/Transaction.notice_error