# How to send manually exceptions to NewRelic (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, exception, newrelic

How I can send rescued exceptions to NewRelic ?

I have a test file rpm.rb:

```
require 'newrelic_rpm'
NewRelic::Agent.manual_start
begin
  "2" + 3
rescue TypeError => e
  puts "whoa !"
  NewRelic::Agent.agent.error_collector.notice_error( e )
end
```

I start it with:

```
NEWRELIC_ENABLE=true ruby rpm.rb
```

The content of log/newrelic_agent.log:

```
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Environment: development
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] WARN : No dispatcher detected.
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Application: xxx (Development)
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Installing Net instrumentation
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Audit log enabled at '.../log/newrelic_audit.log'
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Finished instrumentation
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Reading configuration from config/newrelic.yml
[05/14/13 ... (87691)] INFO : Starting Agent shutdown
```

The content of log/newrelic_audit.log

```
[2013-05-14 ... (87691)] : REQUEST: collector.newrelic.com:443/agent_listener/12/74901a11b7ff1a69aba11d1797830c8c1af41d56/get_redirect_host?marshal_format=json
[2013-05-14 ... (87691)] : REQUEST BODY: []
```

Nothing is reported to NewRelic, why ?

I saw this already: [Is there way to push NewRelic error manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607321/is-there-way-to-push-newrelic-error-manually)

Comment: does the `raise` keyword help?

Comment: I don't want let see our customers the stacktrace :), thats why the rescue is in my example, but thanks

Comment: This may be too obvious, but NR does not phone home by default when running in Development mode unless you change the config file.

Comment: That seems to be substantiated by `WARN : No dispatcher detected.`

Comment: I work at New Relic on the newrelic_rpm gem. What version of the newrelic_rpm gem are you using? Older versions will refuse to start at all unless a known dispatcher (web server or background task framework) is detected, and it looks like you may be hitting taht. Also, you should use `NewRelic::Agent.notice_error`, since that's our public API, not the version on the error_collector.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent an hour trying to test this from production console.
This is what finally got it working:

1. Make sure `monitor_mode: true` is set in newrelic.yml for the appropriate environment
2. Make sure to run the rails console with `NEW_RELIC_AGENT_ENABLED=true NEWRELIC_ENABLE=true rails c`
3. Make sure to use the public-api method call `NewRelic::Agent.notice_error(exception)`

Naturally, `.notice_error` will work as expected when called from a non-console process like the web-server.

Comment: the "4th" point is not really straightforward if you come from other services like Rollbar - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `monitor_mode: true` in config/newrelic.yml

```
development:
  <<: *default_settings
  # Turn off communication to New Relic service in development mode (also
  # 'enabled').
  # NOTE: for initial evaluation purposes, you may want to temporarily
  # turn the agent on in development mode.
  monitor_mode: true

  # Rails Only - when running in Developer Mode, the New Relic Agent will
  # present performance information on the last 100 transactions you have
  # executed since starting the mongrel.
  # NOTE: There is substantial overhead when running in developer mode.
  # Do not use for production or load testing.
  developer_mode: true
```