# How to manually push errors to NewRelic in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, newrelic

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12607321/2479481) covers how to manually notice errors in NewRelic in Ruby.

I need to do the same thing in C#.

How can I manually send errors to NewRelic in .NET?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [NewRelic's .NET Api](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/net-agent/net-agent-api/noticeerror-net-agent), you can do this with

```
NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError(ex);
```

where `ex` is an `Exception`.

Comment: should this be part of your original question or are you stating this as an answer that solves your initial question...?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I am [answering my own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this across all WebApi as an ExceptionLogger to log errors into New Relic

Add the following class to your project

```
public class NewRelicExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.NoticeError(context.ExceptionContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

and register it `Global.asax.cs` under `Application_Start()`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //...
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new NewRelicExceptionLogger());

}
```